Is the word count of my non-fiction book too large?
I have written a non-fiction book. The title is A Meaningful Life. It discusses the current trend of substance use, the insatiable appetite for drugs, the current death rate from overdoses, and the criminal activity associated with this trend. It also offers analysis of the trend and specific management suggestions. I am a physician and a specialist in this field.
The book has 16 chapters and a word count of 106,000. I cannot easily cut that down as the subject is vast and complicated, but made simple. I want to submit it to an agent, but I am afraid the word count will not go in my favour. Will the length be a problem?

Two things:
Non-fiction is commonly submitted to agents or publishers as a proposal, and usually before it is being written.
Word count for non-fiction aimed at the general public (not scholars) is commonly somewhere between 50,000 and 80,000 words or thereabouts. Biographies and histories can be a bit above 100,000 words.
